# Player 1 always wins. Is this because random.shuffle isn' truely random or have I made a logic error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

The code always shows player 1 as the winner despite random.shuffle supposedly making the odds random every time. There isn't any straight forward pattern I have been able to see in how the cards are shuffled or how player 1 always wins the game, as they don't always win each round. Regardless they always win the whole game.

I want to know if this is a problem with me using sudo-random shuffling or have I made a logic error at some point that I failed to notice.

I have tried putting prints in at various points to try and see if I am getting unforeseen/undesired outcomes at different point but haven't noticed any weird outputs.

I tried double shuffling the values to see if that changed anything but the outcome was still always player 1.

Player 2 does win when I don't shuffle so I assume all the maths and checks are right.

```
cards = ['r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','r6','r7','r8','r9','r10','b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b9','b10','y1','y2','y3','y4','y5','y6','y7','y8','y9','y10']

#cardShuffler
def cardShuffler(cards):
    from random import shuffle
    shuffle(cards)
    print(cards)
    return(cards)


#cardArrayDeciphers
#colour
def cardColour(selectedCard):
    colour = selectedCard[0] #takes the letter on the card intidacting colour
    return colour
#number
def cardNum(selectedCard):
    number = int(selectedCard[1]) #takes number in a card and convert str to int
    return number

#winnerCalc
def winnerCalc(p1Card, p2Card):
    colour1 = cardColour(p1Card)
    colour2 = cardColour(p2Card)
    num1 = cardNum(p1Card)
    num2 = cardNum(p2Card)
    #pattern should go red > black > yellow > red
    if(colour1 == "r")and(colour2 == "b"):
        winner = ("p1")
    elif(colour1 == "b")and(colour2 == "y"):
        winner = ("p1")
    elif(colour1 == "y")and(colour2 == "r"):
        winner = ("p1")
    elif num1 > num2:
        winner = ("p1")
    else:
        winner = ("p2")
    print("winner "+str(winner)) #debug
    return winner

#gameVals
searchVal = -1
p1WinCards = []
p2WinCards = []
cards = cardShuffler(cards) #function = cardShuffle

#gameLoop [player 1 always wins!]
while (searchVal != 29):
    p1Given = searchVal + 1 #where the code looks for p1 card
    p2Given = searchVal + 2
    p1Card = cards[p1Given]
    p2Card = cards[p2Given]
    searchVal = p2Given
    winner = winnerCalc(p1Card, p2Card) #function = winnerCalc
    if winner == "p1": #giving the winner all the cards
        p1WinCards.append(p1Card)
        p1WinCards.append(p2Card)
    else:
        p2WinCards.append(p1Card)
        p2WinCards.append(p2Card)
    print("p1 " +str(len(p1WinCards))) #debug
    print("p2 " +str(len(p2WinCards))) #debug
if len(p1WinCards) > len(p2WinCards): #finding the final winner by the length of win cards
     winnerAbsolute = p1WinCards
     winnerName = input("Player 1 won! Please enter your name: ")
else:
    winnerAbsolute = p2WinCards
    winnerName = input("Player 2 won! Please enter your name: ")
```

I expect the output for winnerAbsolute to be sudo_random but the result is always player 1.

Comment: Hey , could we have a quick look at your cards dataset . To be honest , I just wanted to try the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statements heavily favor p1 to win. Example code where I expect 'p2' to win since p2 has the superior color:

```
colour1 = 'b'
colour2 = 'r'
num1 = 2
num2 = 1

if(colour1 == "r")and(colour2 == "b"):
    print("p1")
elif(colour1 == "b")and(colour2 == "y"):
    print("p1")
elif(colour1 == "y")and(colour2 == "r"):
    print("p1")
elif num1 > num2:
    print("p1")
else:
    print("p2")

>>> p1
```

Player1 wins here because there is no check to see if player 2 has the better color. To properly check for the right winner you can modify your if-statements to the following logic:

```
colour1 = 'b'
colour2 = 'r'
num1 = 2
num2 = 1

if (colour1 == "r" and colour2 == "b") or (colour1 == "b" and colour2 == "y") or (colour1 == "y" and colour2 == "r"):
    print("p1")
elif (colour2 == "r" and colour1 == "b") or (colour2 == "b" and colour1 == "y") or (colour2 == "y" and colour1 == "r"):
    print("p2")
elif num1 > num2:
    print("p1")
else:
    print("p2")

>>> p2
```

In which you can refactor the last elif and else to the following line of code:

```
colour1 = 'b'
colour2 = 'r'
num1 = 2
num2 = 1

if (colour1 == "r" and colour2 == "b") or (colour1 == "b" and colour2 == "y") or (colour1 == "y" and colour2 == "r"):
    print("p1")
elif (colour2 == "r" and colour1 == "b") or (colour2 == "b" and colour1 == "y") or (colour2 == "y" and colour1 == "r"):
    print("p2")
else:
    print("p1" if num1 > num2 else "p2")

>>> p2
```

Answer (score 0):

first off, fun playing with your game.
Second, as I suspected, the error always lies in the multiple if statement, that are particularly tricky as you think you are thorough and in the ned it bites you !

So to be clear , let's take an example:

```
p1Card = y8 ,p2Card = b1
```

And let's run it through:

```
if(colour1 == "r")and(colour2 == "b") # False
    winner = ("p1")
elif(colour1 == "b")and(colour2 == "y")# False
    winner = ("p1")
elif(colour1 == "y")and(colour2 == "r")# False
    winner = ("p1")
elif num1 > num2: # True
    winner = ("p1")
else:
    winner = ("p2")
```

Therefore, winner P1 whereas it should have been P2.
Multiple ways to avoid this, but this should be left to you to figure out :)